# why list in object is not showing correctly in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign a value to class variable is assiging it for all instances of that object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929969/assign-a-value-to-class-variable-is-assiging-it-for-all-instances-of-that-object)

I need a help. I am used to java development and new I am starting python. And I write a simple class which contain a list of string. and In the main function I create a list of this object and I would like to print the content of the list of object. But my function print all the string of all the object together.
Here is an example

```
class FastData:
        name=''
        lines=[]

        def __init__ (self, name):
                self.name=name

        def setName(self,name):
                self.name = name

        def addLine(self, line):
                self.lines.append(line)

        def getLines(self):
                return self.lines

        def getName(self):
                return self.name

        def printList(self):

                for myline in self.lines:
                        print myline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listes = []

    newData = FastData("Single")
    newData.addLine("1")
    newData.addLine("2")

    listes.append(newData)



    newData1 = FastData("Double")
    newData1.addLine("111")
    newData1.addLine("222")
    listes.append(newData1)

    for myList in listes:
        print myList.getName()
        myList.printList()
```

and Here is what I got like output

```
Single
1
2
111
222

Double
1
2
111
222
```

Thank for your help

Thathug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, all instances of `FastData` share the same `lines` object. Fix it like so:

```
class FastData:

    # note that I've removed `name' and `lines' from here

    def __init__ (self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.lines = []
```

The reason your code worked the way it did was that `lines` was a property of the *class*, not of each individual *instance* of the class.